# I can not add plugins in Muse Sequencer

Tags: sound

I use **Ubuntu 16.10** and installed **Muse Sequencer** through the Ubuntu repository. But when I open the program, I can not see all the plugins installed on my computer, I have **Calf-FluidSynther, DrumGizmo** and others but it does not appear to select. I have not found in the settings the place to insert **lv2 and LADSPA** plugins contained in my machine. I ask you to help.

Comment: I am now using Ubuntu Studio but the same problem continues with MuSe, I can not see the Calf plugins in it, I can already see DrumGizmo but Calf-FluidSynth does not. I did not find in the program something like a path setting to the plugins folder or a config file that lists all the already inserted plugins. And also I do not know why, in Ubuntu Studio when I inserted a plugin the MuSe hangs and closes.

Comment: I'm using now the Qtractor which is doing pretty much everything that MuSe would do, just have not found the drums map button yet.

Comment: I returned this morning to Ubuntu 16.10 because with Ubuntu Studio I was not able to configure all the audio outputs. And the problem with MuSe continues he does not see the plugins installed, just a few. I'll use the same Qtractor.

Answer (score 0):

I went to the MuSe sequencer website and downloaded version 3.0, and this solved the entire LV2 plugin compatibility problem that has in the standard version of Ubuntu repositories. To compile MuSe 3.0 you need to install all the main and optional dependencies that are in the Readme in the MuSe folder.